# Classification of X-ray Image using machine learning

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision

By what way i can classify X-ray image's features with the help of any machine learning algorithm so that when next time i test a input by sending an individual's X-ray image feature , it should send me whether or not this X-ray is present or not in the database... i have found out the features using matlab of around 20 images.

Comment: It depends on how your feature space looks. I would bet on SVM without having a look at the data. Try SVM with RBF kernel. Also 20 images is too less. You can try kNN method also for classifying.

Comment: @parag..i m looking for more images but they are bit hard to find as i m focusing on one part of the body.. secondly can you explain me how to use this SVM technique more precisely as i m totally new in machine learning..

Comment: read the documentation of MATLAB's `svmtrain` and `svmclassify`. Also you can have a look at `libsvm` library.

Answer (score 1):

If the X-rays you're matching are identical, you don't really need to use machine learning. Just do a pixel-wise match and check if the images are say 99% identical (to make up for illumination differences in scanning). In MATLAB, you can do this by simply taking the absolute pixel-wise difference of the two images, and then counting the number of pixels that are different by more than a pre-defined threshold.

If the X-rays are not identical, and you know what features occur repeatedly when the same portion of the body of the same person is X-rayed multiple times, then machine learning would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It kinds of like face recognition where you input a human face image and then machine learning output whether this face is in your dataset. For your problem, the simplest way i can think of  is just define a "distance metric" to measure the similarity of two image features and set a threshold to judge whether they are the same.